# Where can I download Rational Application Developer (RAD) 7 and WebSphere Application Server (WAS) 7?

Tags: server, rad, was, websphere, window-load

I have been searching for RAD 7 and WAS 7 from IBM but could not find the relevant installers. I have an application that requires this version and I still have not been able to open it. I clarify that I need the specific version and not a different one (Neither previous nor superior).

I am grateful if you can tell me where I can download the versions of the indicated applications, no matter if they are the test versions or they are housed in unofficial repositories.

Comment: I have the similar requirements to install WAS 7.0 and RAD 9.0 but I have got below options disabled. Please suggest. Thanks.

Download 1 of 11: WebSphere Application Server V7.0 Quick Start Guide CZ0KHML.zip Download 2 of 11: WebSphere Application Server V7.0 for Windows on x86-64 bit, Multilingual C1G0TML.zip

Also please let me know if there is any other location where I can download WAS7.0 for Windows. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What operating system does your application run?  For Linux use these PARTNUMBERS CZ0KHML.zip
Download 2 of 9:
WebSphere Application Server V7.0 for Linux on PowerPC, 32-bit, Multilingual
C1G03ML.tar.gz. C1G03ML